# Error in likert: All items (columns) must have the same number of levels in R

Tags: r, likert

My data:

```
        Q5         Q6          Q7
1   Not Agree   Neutral     Not Agree
2   Not Agree   Neutral     Neutral
3   Not Agree   Agree       Agree
4   Not Agree   Agree       Neutral
5   Neutral     Not Agree   Neutral
6   Not Agree   Agree       Neutral
7   Not Agree   Neutral     Neutral
8   Neutral     Agree       Neutral
9   Agree       Neutral     Not Agree
10  Neutral     Agree       Neutral
```

```
Q567[1:3] <- lapply(Q567[1:3], factor, levels= c("Agree", "Neutral", "Not Agree"), ordered = TRUE)

likert(Q567) %>%
  plot(type = "bar")
```

What my data looks like 
[image: What my data looks like]

I converted them into factor with levels, why I still get the error

```
Error in likert(Q567) : All items (columns) must have the same number of levels
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`. We cannot copy/paste data from images, or understand its structure.

Answer (score 16):

I've had the same problem, and found that the set I was working with was a tibble, rather than a data.frame:

```
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: This is a huge time-saver and should be marked as the answer. Will be the first thing I try for future issues, too.

Answer (score 0):

You have only recoded the first three columns of your dataframe to be factors, but you pass the entire dataframe to `likert`. The `likert` function expects the variables in `Q567` to be factors. So I believe you have additional columns in the dataframe that are not, which is causing your error.

You should do something like:

```
likert(Q567[,1:3]) %>% 
  plot(type = 'bar')
```

Comment: It still shows as "Error in likert(Q567[, 1:3]) : All items (columns) must have the same number of levels"

Comment: Did you run `Q567[1:3] <- lapply(Q567[1:3], factor, levels= c("Agree", "Neutral", "Not Agree"), ordered = TRUE)` first before trying the above?

Comment: Yes I did, it looks like have levels when i do the summary(data). I don't understand why still error

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the data with `dput(head(Q567))`?

Answer (score 0):

These answers (as.data.frame, lapply with factor levels) didn't work for me. It turns out that not all of my variables were factors, some were ordered. So a simple `data <- data %>% mutate_at(cols, factor)` worked for me.